# How to get out of local optimum using simulated annealing?

Tags: heuristics, simulated-annealing

I have a conceptual question. I am working on an optimization project in which I used a simulated annealing metaheuristic to get better solutions. for creating neighbors in SA I have used both SWAP and 2-OPT methods to create neighbors by creating a new sequence. results even for small problem sizes show that 7 out of 10 times when I run the program (with more than 500 iterations) the best objective value achieved is the initial objective value which has been achieved heuristically.
question is what could cause such behavior?

- is it because the initial feasible solution has high quality?
- how much changing the cooling factor and starting temperature will help? (it did not help so far in small instances)
- am I not creating efficient neighbors?

is there something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the percentage, accepted solutions.
For instance, every 100 proposals, print the number of accepted solutions.

- Start with a random solution, not close to optimal one.
- In early phase, >80% should be accepted. If this is not the case, increase the temperature until so.
- In last phase, <10% should be accepted, if this is not the case, lower the stop temperature.
- Cooling scheme has only small influence on solution quality, just lower by cooling factor is good enough, between 0.99 and 0.8. (You can repeat N times on each temperature to increase the proposals)
- You can experiment with different proposals.
- If you apply on traveling salesman, you can 2-opt your output of simulated annealing (SA). Most likely, your SA with a 2-opt to 'clean' the solution, is better than 2-opt without SA.

Hope this helps.